# Python Strings, Loops & Second Loops - Part 2 Patterns

Tags: python, string, loops, design-patterns

I am trying to create some code that creates a very specific pattern that can be run any x amount of times. to duplicate the pattern across the screen.

my intented pattern is a step like/stair pattern repeated across the page

my decomposition is

when run - user enter variable (variable is named x for example)

set up the variables (that would be used to create the pattern)

print name of pattern

max number of range of x (user entered variable*2)

spacing and duplictation

print

```
# Python Program to Print Square Step Pattern

square_side = int(input("Please enter the square Step dimension  : "))

square_base = int(input("Please enter the square base dimension  : "))

print("Square AlphaBet Step Pattern") 
max_side = square_side*2

for i in range(max_side):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        letter = " _"
    else:
        letter = " |"
    
    print(" "*(max_side-i-1) + letter*3)


for i in range(square_side):
    for j in range(7):
        print('{}{}{}'.format(2*(square_base-i)*' ','_|', 2*(i+1)*' '),end='')
    print()
```

[image: the above code leaves me with this - i want to alter it so that it removes the pattern that is circled in red]

Comment: What's your question? What is your expected vs. actual output?

Comment: Also, please copy and paste the output as text, not an image. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)